# mod_security: disable cookie verification causing SQLI false positive

Tags: centos7, mod-security

I'm trying to configure mod_security on CentOS 7 for apache2.4 with the OWASP ruleset.
The thing is my web app generates a cookie with -- characters and it gets flagged as an SQLI. I read the following article [how to whitelist a certain cookie string in ModSecurity](https://serverfault.com/questions/562043/how-to-whitelist-a-certain-cookie-string-in-modsecurity) to try and disable the guilty cookie but I had no luck with that : I still get a 403 forbidden.

What I tried was to add to my whitelist.conf (in the modsecurity.d/ folder) the following rule: SecRuleUpdateTargetByMsg "SQL Comment Sequence Detected." !REQUEST_COOKIES:/^*Titlebox* (on the same line ofc):

I get a 403 forbidden if the cookie is present.
I tried to create a file as indicated in the article and added the rule to a 
/etc/httpd/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_61_customrules.conf file and still nothing:I get blocked.

It's problematic since this cookie is legit.
Did the way to fix that problem change in the current version of mod_security ? Or I'm still doing things wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

edit:

With the rule per ID looking like this:
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981172 !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/
It works

With the one per Message like this:
SecRuleUpdateTargetByMsg "SQL Comment Sequence Detected." !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox
It does not work and still blocks my cookie

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked to was about whitelisting rule 981231 which looks like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(/\*!?|\*/|[';]--|--[\s\r\n\v\f]|(?:--[^-]*?-)|([^\-&])#.*?[\s\r\n\v\f]|;?\\x00)" "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'8',accuracy:'8',\
id:'981231',t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,block,\
msg:'SQL Comment Sequence Detected.'\
,severity:'2',capture,logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-19',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1',tag:'OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1',tag:'PCI/6.5.2',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+1,setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

You are trying to whitelist 981172 which looks like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES "([\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\:\;\"\'\´\’\‘\`\<\>].*?){8,}" "phase:2,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,block,\
id:'981172',rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'8',\
msg:'Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded',\
capture,logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.1} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+1,setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/RESTRICTED_SQLI_CHARS-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

As you can see the message is different for this rule, so you are whitelisting the wrong message. Hence why it is not working for you.

Comment: I removed both and probably linked the wrong one but my problem was whitelisting a message, I had to whitelist the ID instead.

My whitelist conf file is as follows:
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981231 !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981172 !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/

Comment: #SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981231 !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/

SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981172 !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/

SecRuleUpdateTargetByMsg "SQL Comment Sequence Detected." !REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES:/^TitleBox/


This config still blocks my cookie, which is the actual problem.

Comment: You are not including the full msg value. Only the first it. I'm not sure if SecRuleUpdateTargetByMsg handles that so try including the full msg value (Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded)